# Buffer for network roads in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, network, road

How can I create "buffers" or vector from values ​​from a layer of points, where the "buffers" are "tied" to the streets?

Example: A bus station, I would like to create vectors within 100 m range with streets, from the point, regardless of the direction, following the road system.

I need to make a linear "buffer", following the system road, to identify the distance the bus station will cover on every street.

[image]

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain a graphic explaining what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I need to make a " buffer " linear. following the sistem road. To identify , as far as the bus station will cover every street .

Comment: You still need to create an AFTER image.  Words are not going to suffice

Comment: ok , I want to create it. from a point following the road lines . Eg 100m from the airport .

Comment: It has wide, has length . ex 100m

Comment: but, i don't use postgis. only have for QGIS?? thanks

Comment: I've added a bounty to try and attract a QGIS-only answer to the duplicate question. Let's see if anyone comes up with a solution.